# How to get the data plotted correctly using matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have 3 lists containing means:

```
FFA_mean = ['0.511', '0.704', '0.922', '0.764', '1.084']
LG_mean = ['0.018', '0.001', '-0.003', '-0.005', '-0.004']
PPA_mean = ['1.161', '1.000', '0.875', '0.785', '0.336']
```

And their respective confidence intervals:

```
FFA_ci = [0.245, 0.24892, 0.3038, 0.22736, 0.24304]
LG_ci = [0.19992, 0.21952, 0.147, 0.1666, 0.1862]
PPA_ci = [0.27440000000000003, 0.28615999999999997, 0.34496, 0.30968, 0.1862]
```

And here is the code I am using to plot this data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

barWidth = 0.3

n= 5
r1 = np.arange(n)


plt.bar(r1, FFA_mean, width = barWidth, color = 'pink', label='FFA')
plt.bar(r1+barWidth, LG_mean, width = barWidth, color = 'orange', label='Lingual Gyrus')
plt.bar(r1+barWidth*2, PPA_mean, width = barWidth, color = 'cyan', label='PPA')


plt.xticks([r + barWidth for r in range(len(FFA_mean))], ['House', 'Chair', 'Shoe', 'Bottle', 'Face'])
plt.ylabel('Percentage BOLD Signal Change')
plt.xlabel('Stimuli Class')
plt.title('FEATQuery Analysis for FFA, Lingual Gyrus and PPA')
plt.legend()


plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

Which is wrong data, the bars do not follow the actual values of my means and I don't know why. Could anyone spot what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your mean values in all the three lists (`FFA_mean, LG_mean, PPA_mean`) are of string types. You need to cast them to float type to get the correct order of values. One way to do so is to use `map` function to convert all your strings to float type. `map` will return a generator which is not accepted by `plt.bar()` therefore you convert it back to list.

```
FFA_mean = list(map(float,['0.511', '0.704', '0.922', '0.764', '1.084']))
LG_mean = list(map(float,['0.018', '0.001', '-0.003', '-0.005', '-0.004']))
PPA_mean = list(map(float,['1.161', '1.000', '0.875', '0.785', '0.336']))
```

**Alternative** using list comprehension would be for instance

```
FFA_mean = ['0.511', '0.704', '0.922', '0.764', '1.084']
FFA_mean = [float(i) for i in FFA_mean]
```

and similarly for the other two lists.

[image]